# jQuery trigger not working in IE. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, triggers

```
$('#XynBp0').find('input').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('value') == 'Cancel'){
        $(this).trigger('click');
    }
});
```

doesn't work in IE7

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work". Does it find the input elements? What does `$(this).attr('value')` contain when you walk through each input element? Or is it the trigger that doesn't fire?

Comment: AS i said in my title, "jQuery trigger" doesn't work. I'm not sure why but even though the element in question is found, the trigger doesn't fire. Either that or the fire does nothing.

Comment: @syn4k so you know for a fact that the buttons are found in IE7, and the `value = "Cancel"` condition is met? You are 100% sure it's just the `trigger` that doesn't work?

Comment: @Pekka, Yes, I am 100% certain. It's weird that even though the element is found the trigger fails.

Comment: Strange. Can you show the HTML code to go with it?

Comment: just fyi, you can do it in one line: `$("#XynBp0 input[value='Cancel']").trigger('click');`

Comment: @syn4k Also see this comment: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#comment-48277488 `Using .trigger('click') will not trigger the native click event.` Maybe you'll need to use @Mouhannad's workaround

Comment: @Pekka,Thanks again but my code is over three thousand lines long. I don't think it will quite fit here...not to mention, 2,997 lines have nothing to do with this.

Comment: @syn4k - Post the **pertinent** code here. Create a minimal duplication of the undesired behavior on jsFiddle and link to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's strange but try to create a custom event

```
$('#XynBp0 input').bind('custom',function(){
 //code
})


$('#XynBp0').find('input').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('value') == 'Cancel'){
        $(this).trigger('custom');
    }
});
```

Does this work?

Comment: No, but thank you. I tried this and put an alert in the custom function but nothing alerted. Very strange that this works in any browser if it fails in IE7

Comment: maybe if you share the rest of the code we can give a better answer!

Answer (score 2):

`$.click()` (or `$.trigger('click')`) doesn't simulate a mouse click; it fires off any *onclick* events bound to that element. If you haven't assigned an *onclick* event to that input you're searching for, nothing will happen.

It sounds like you're trying to submit the form with a traditional submit button (e.g. `<input type="submit" value="Cancel">`). If that's the case, you may have to use `$(yourform).submit()` to submit the form, in combination with some handling of the data sent to the server to simulate clicking the Cancel button.

Comment: Thanks Jason but this works perfectly fine in Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Is it wrapped in a dom ready event? Might help if you provide more code.

```
$(function () {

    $('#XynBp0').find('input').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('value') == 'Cancel') {
            $(this).trigger('click');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippit doesn't make any sense, you are clicking inputs if they are canceled?

Here's some things to clean up in your code

```
$('input','#XynBp0').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ( this.value === 'Cancel' ) { //Don't need jQuery here
    $this.trigger('click');  //Probably don't need it here either
  }
});
```

What does click even do?  If you are trying to submit a form, use form.submit();

Comment: Again, this works as it should in ALL other browsers. It makes perfect sense. The code fires the click event on that particular input.

Comment: Can you post the HTML and the rest of the code?  I can get this working in all browsers, if I had an idea of what you are trying to do.